# Can Youtube annotations link to Google play?

Tags: android, youtube

I want an annotation in my app promo movie, which links to my app on Google play. It says in the documentation "you can choose whether you want the annotation to link to another video, your channel, a playlist, a fundraising site or direct the users to subscribe to your channel." Does this mean that it is not possible to add an annotation to Google play?

Comment: I'd also like to know this.

Comment: Youtube now says that cards should replace annotations. I have tried to get them to work on mobiles, but they do not show up. See my other thread "youtube cards are not seen on mymobile".